# Bootstrap Navbar links not justifying right as expected

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am practicing with basic BootStrap Navbars, but I am not getting the intended result. I've spent the last half hour trying to get my navbar links to align left, and appear just right of my brand link. Instead my links align right and stack over each other. What is the best way to fix this?

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Navbar Practice</a>
    <div class="" id="navbarText">
      <ul class=" navbar-nav justify-content-end mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item ">
          <a class="nav-link " href="#">First Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Second Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand">
          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Navbar Practice</a>
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
```

Here's my solution, you should add the class navbar-expand and it should give  you the desired outcome.

Answer (score 1):

```html
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <div class="container">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Navbar Practice</a>
        <div class="row bg-white" id="navbarText">
          <div class="col-6">
            <a href="#">one</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6">
          <a href="#">two</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
```

Hi! you can use row and col class